# How to fix error in codeigniter4 and date_format?

Tags: codeigniter, datetime, codeigniter-4

I am making this query in codeigniter4 and I am stuck

```
public function consultasHoy(){

        $data = $this->consultas->select('pacientes.*,consultas_hc.*')
            ->from('consultas_hc')
            ->join('pacientes','consultas_hc.identificacion = pacientes.identificacion')
            ->where(date_format('consultas_rc.reConsulta','%Y-%m-%d'),date_format(now(),'%Y-%m-%d'))
            ->orderBy('consultas_hc.reConsulta', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        return json_encode($data);
    }
```

and it returns this error

> date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string
> given

Answer (score 0):

this was the solution used, thanks for the help

```
 public function consultasHoy(){

        helper('date');
        $hoy=(new \DateTime("now"))->format("Y-m-d");

        $builder = $this->consultas->select('*');
        $builder->join('pacientes', 'pacientes.identificacion=consultas_hc.identificacion');
        $builder->where("DATE(reConsulta)", $hoy);
        $query   = $builder->get();


        return json_encode($query->getResult());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting date straightforwardly from the database to your controller then you can print date format in view like below:

```
$YourDate = $row->start_date;
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($YourDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your where clause with this line of code:

```
 $where="DATE_FORMAT('consultas_rc.reConsulta','%Y-%m-01')= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() ,'%Y-%m-01')";
        ->where($where);
```